# Max row count (top) customer per year

Tags: sql-server, join, count, group-by

Doing some stats page for my skydiving club I have two SQL queries I would like to merge.
One shows the top three jumpers with the most jumps on the first load this year:

```
select  top 3 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY count(1) desc) AS Nr 
        , vc.sCust as Name
        , count(1) as JumpsCount
from    dbo.ViewInvoice vi with(nolock)
join    dbo.viewCust vc
on      vi.wCustId = vc.wCustId
where   year(vi.dtProcess) = year(getdate())
        and vi.nMani = 1
group by vc.sCust 
order by count(1) desc
```

OUTPUT:

```
--  Nr  Name            JumpsCount
--  1   Tom Awesome         17
--  2   Alan Jackson        16
--  3   John Thebest        13
```

The next query shows all the years of jumping in the DB:

```
select  distinct year(vi.dtProcess) As Datum
from    dbo.ViewInvoice vi 
order by 1
```

OUTPUT:

```
--  Datum
--  2010
--  ...
--  2014
```

What I would like is to get a query that merge the results with an output like this:

```
--  Datum   Nr  Name                Jumpscount
--  2010    1   Some OldVeteran         100
--  2010    2   Alan Jackson            96
--  2010    3   Gordon McGann           89
--  ...
--  2014    1   Tom Awesome             17
--  2014    2   Alan Jackson            16
--  2014    3   John Thebest            13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed to `RANK` so jumpers with same amount of jumps gets the same postion.

```
WITH JumpsPerYear AS (
    SELECT YEAR(dtProcess) AS [Year]
          ,wCustId
          ,COUNT(1) AS JumpsCount
    FROM ViewInvoice
    WHERE nMani = 1 -- first load/manifest number
    GROUP BY YEAR(dtProcess)
            ,wCustId
)
,RankPerYear AS (
    SELECT [Year]
          ,wCustId
          ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Year] ORDER BY JumpsCount DESC) AS [Rank]
          ,JumpsCount
    FROM JumpsPerYear
)
SELECT RankPerYear.[Year] AS Datum
      ,RankPerYear.[Rank] AS Nr
      ,ViewCust.sCust AS Name
      ,RankPerYear.JumpsCount
FROM RankPerYear
     INNER JOIN ViewCust
         ON ViewCust.wCustId = RankPerYear.wCustId
WHERE RankPerYear.[Rank] <= 3
ORDER BY RankPerYear.[Year]
      ,RankPerYear.[Rank]
```